# Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error applying config update to existing channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, raft

I was adding a new orderer in a network configured with RAFT consensus protocol so I have added and modified by config file and included the newly created orderer's TLS certs in the consensus-type section.

I have followed all the steps to make the channel configuration update transaction upto the signconfigtx update but when I try to do the final peer channel update then it gets failed and it produces this error:

```
2019-08-22 10:59:48.212 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error applying config update to existing channel 'mychannel': error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Value]  /Channel/Orderer/ConsensusType not satisfied: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied
```

Even though i have signed this update from admin of both the orgs but still I am getting this error. Please help me and let me know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so I have resolved this issue. I was signing the channel update transaction using wrong MSP and admin certs. The update of this type should be signed of by OrdererMSP so I have to use Orderer's admin credentials to sign this update.

Comment: How to do using oredermsp?

Comment: @DeepakBhavsar see my answer below. I had the same question as you.

Answer (score 1):

Some channel changes required signing the update with Orderer MSP Identity. Thus, expanding on the answer above, to setup the OrdererMSP Admin Identity you need to set these environmental variables. If you are using the `fabric-samples/test-network` to play around, it's likely that you can use the values below as is, having set them from `test-network` folder.

```bash
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="OrdererMSP"
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=${PWD}/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/tlscacerts/tls-localhost-9054-ca-orderer.pem
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=${PWD}/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=localhost:7050
```